# Why does scalar sub { (@x, @y) }->() return scalar @y?

Tags: perl

There are a few things I "know" about Perl:

- lists flatten
- functions take and return lists

So if I have this:

```
sub my_test {
  my @x = qw(a b c);
  my @y = qw(x y z t);
  return (@x, @y); 
} 

say my_test; # a b c x y z t
say scalar my_test;
```

I expect either of two result values:

- `7`, because that's how many items there are in the list `qw(a b c x y z t)`. Indeed, this is what I get from `scalar sub { @{[ qw(a b c x y z t) ]} }->()`.
- `'t'`, because if you interpret the commas as the comma operator (*sigh*) you get `('a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z', 't')` which evaluates to `'t'`. Indeed, this is what I get from `scalar sub { qw(a b c x y z t) }->()`.

What you do get instead is… 4, without warning. Why did I get a mix of list flattening and comma operator?

Similar story with hashes and this rather popular pattern:

```
sub default_override_hash {
  my %defaults = (foo => 'bar', egg => 'quuz');
  my %values = @_;
  my %overrides = (__baz => '');
  return (%defaults, %values, %overrides);
}

scalar default_override_hash; # '1/8'
```

How does `scalar` know that `default_override_hash` returned three hashes, and it should not only just get `%overrides` (and not everything, and not `''`), but its scalar representation as a hash?

Comment: I guess I expect `scalar` to be like `sub my_scalar { my @input = @_; scalar @scalar; } `

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8232951/133939

Answer (score 7):

The most important point is: Lists don't flatten. (Lists are flat, but they don't flatten, because to do that they'd have to be nested first.)

`,` (the comma operator) in list context is list concatenation. `A , B` in list context evaluates `A` and `B` in list context, then concatenates the results.

`A , B` in scalar context works like C (or JavaScript): It evaluates `A` in void context, then evaluates (and returns) `B` in scalar context. (`A , B` in void context works the same, but evaluates `B` in void context too.)

In `return X`, the context of `X` is the context of the function call itself. Thus `sub my_test { return X } scalar my_test` is like `scalar X`. **It's like `return` dynamically looks at the context the current sub call is in, and evaluates its operand expression accordingly.**

[`perldoc perlsub` says](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION):

> A `return` statement may be used to exit a subroutine, optionally specifying the returned value, which will be evaluated in the appropriate context (list, scalar, or void) depending on the context of the subroutine call.)

As described above, `@x, @y` in scalar context evaluates `@x` in void context (which for an array does nothing), then evaluates and returns `@y` in scalar context. An array in scalar context yields the number of elements it contains.

The same logic applies to `%defaults, %values, %overrides`. [`,` is left-associative](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity), so this parses as `(%defaults , %values) , %overrides`.
This evaluates `%defaults , %values` in void context (which in turn evaluates `%defaults`, then `%values` in void context, which has no effect), then evaluates and returns `%overrides` in scalar context. A hash in scalar context returns a (rather useless) string describing hash internals.

Comment: The bolded sentence is wrong. `return` doesn't look at the context at all. Even if it did, `return` is evaluated *after* the comma operator, so what it does at run-time couldn't possibly have any effect on the comma operator. That means it's completely wrong to say that `return` is the one that checks the caller's context (or that it's like it did); it's the comma operator that does that.

Comment: The correct wording would be: **The comma operator (`,`) dynamically looks at the context in which the current sub was called, and evaluates its operand expression accordingly.**

Comment: @ikegami `return @z` has no comma but still evaluates `@z` in the context of the current sub.

Comment: @ikegami It's wrong to say that `return` is evaluated after the comma. The comma is evaluated as _part of_ the evaluation of the `return`.

Comment: @Oktalist, That's because the `@z` operator also looks.

Comment: @ikegami In `sub { @z; return 42 }` the `@z` doesn't look. So it's particular to whatever expression is the operand of the `return`. So the correct wording would be **The operand of the `return` dynamically looks...** And I'm not sure how that differs from melpomene's wording in practical terms.

Comment: @Oktalist, That's a different `@z` operator. [It does look at its context](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/be2c0c650b028f54e427f2469a59942edfdff8a9:/pp.c#l91), although that `@z` doesn't need to go as far as looking at the sub's context. /// Sure, that wording would work too. That's the general phrasing, whereas mine was specific to the example in question.

Comment: @ikegami No, the comma operator only looks at its own context to determine the context of its operands. It's `return` that's the weird one by loooking up the call stack (at runtime).

Comment: @ikegami There is no list. `return` supplies scalar context to its operand in this example. And it doesn't matter when `return` is evaluated; this is about context propagation.

Comment: @ikegami `,` is not a list constructor. It's either a sequencing operator (in scalar/void context) or a concatenation operator (in list context). There is no list in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118257/discussion-between-melpomene-and-ikegami).

Comment: The last expression(s) of a sub gets their context from the caller, not from `return` (which may not even be present).